# How to filter an array by date

Tags: angular

i want to be able to display my array and be able to filter by date. 
for example in between "01-02-2017" and "02-02-2017".

ive tried doing this but i dont think im implementing it correctly

```
export class AppComponent {
  snapshots = [
    { date: '01-02-2017', rooms: 2869, users: 1783, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-05-2017', rooms: 2769, users: 1655, location: 'All' },
    { date: '03-02-2017', rooms: 2025, users: 1911, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-02-2017', rooms: 1278, users: 1167, location: 'All' },
    { date: '02-02-2017', rooms: 2028, users: 1940, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-10-2017', rooms: 2113, users: 2001, location: 'All' },
    { date: '03-02-2017', rooms: 2654, users: 1841, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-02-2017', rooms: 1264, users: 1140, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-02-2017', rooms: 2918, users: 2557, location: 'All' },
    { date: '01-20-2017', rooms: 2160, users: 2112, location: 'All' }
  ];
  start;
  end;

   ngOnInit() { 

   }

filter(){
  this.snapshots = this.snapshots.filter(m => {
  if ( m.date > this.start && m.date < this.end)
  return this.snapshots
  })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getTime()` function of `Date` Class

```
filter(){
  this.snapshots = this.snapshots.filter(m => (m.date.getTime() > this.start.getTime()) && (m.date.getTime() < this.end.getTime()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way will need to convert all of them to JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. You can't just use getTime() on JavaScript strings. Also, you will have to return 'm' instead of 'this.snapshots'.

```
filter(){
  this.snapshots = this.snapshots.filter(m => {
    if (new Date(m.date).getTime() > new Date(this.start).getTime() && new Date(m.date).getTime() < new Date(this.end).getTime()) {
     return m;
    }
  })
}
```